# Installing PyopenNI in windows - boost.python issue

Tags: python, c++, boost, cmake

My main goal is using from `pyOpenNI` for connecting to Kinect xBox One in Python.

For building `pyopenNI` I used this page :
https://github.com/jmendeth/PyOpenNI.

But I encountered with an error not installed boost.
So  I download boost `1.64.0.7z` from this link:
https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_64_0.html

After the unzip in drive `c:`, I follow this page and I used its content for building Boost: https://gist.github.com/madhurjain/ce7cceab88658a6c8ed9379e10967b40.

After testing these steps, I received this message:

> The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built! The following
>   directory should be added to compiler include paths:
>       D:\boost_1_64_0\boost_1_64_0 The following directory should be added to linker library paths:
>       D:\boost_1_64_0\boost_1_64_0\stage\lib CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1928 (message):
>   Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

But again when I wanted to build `pyopenNI`, I receive this error:

> CMake Error at C:/Program
>   Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1928 (message):
>   Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.   Boost version: 1.64.0 
>   Boost include path: C:/Users/YaMahdi/Downloads/boost_1_64_0   Could
>   not find the following Boost libraries:
>             boost_python   No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the   directory containing Boost libraries
>   or BOOST_ROOT to the location of   Boost.

Now I should build `Boost.python` separately. It is a Library binds C++ and Python in a mostly-seamless fashion.

I used this link for building `Boost.python`: 
https://www.mantidproject.org/Building_Boost_Python

Now I receive this error:
python36_d.lib(python36.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86' [on hold]

Could you help me?